# UTF vs character types

Tags: c++, c, unicode, utf

UTF-8 and UTF-16 are variable length - more than 2 bytes may be used. UTF-32 uses 4 bytes. Unicode and UTF are general concepts but I wonder how it is related to C/C++ character types. Windows (WinApi) uses 2 bytes wchar_t. How to handle UTF-8 character which is longer than two bytes ? Even on Linux where wchar_t is 4 bytes long I may get UTF-8 characters which requires 6 bytes. Please exaplain how it works.

Comment: While UTF-8 is a variable length encoding, remember that the "8" in "UTF-8" is the *bit* size of the encoding. It's a byte-wise encoding, where a character may occupy one or more bytes. Which fits very well into the usual `char` width, as it's commonly also 8-bit bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Take care not to confuse a Unicode code point and its representation in a specific encoding. *All* Unicode code points are in the range `0x0`-`0x10FFFF`, which makes them directly storable as 32-bit numbers (that's what UTF-32 does).

UTF-8 <s>can reach 6 bytes per code point</s> [edit: it's actually 4 in its final version so the space issue is moot, but the rest of the paragraph holds] because it requires some overhead to manage its variable length - that's what permits a lot of other code points to be encoded in only 1 or 2 bytes. But when you're receiving <s>a 6-bytes</s> an UTF-8 character and you want to store it into Linux's 32-bit `wchar_t`, you don't store it as-is: you *convert it* to UTF-32, dropping the overhead. Same story with Windows's 16-bit `wchar_t`, except you might end up with 2 16-bit, UTF-16-encoded halves.

Note: a lot of Windows software is actually using UCS-2, which is essentially UTF-16 without the variable length. These won't be able to handle characters that would have required two UTF-16 `wchar_t`'s.

Comment: *"UTF-8 can reach 6 bytes per code point"* If I remember correctly, Unicode standard only allows up to 4 bytes in UTF-8, where `0x10FFFF` should fit.

Comment: @user694733 I quoted OP and ran with it... Apparently UTF-8 did have a 6-byte maximum at some point but it doesn't anymore.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that a single glyph like "ã" does not necessarily correspond to a single Unicode codepoint - it might be LATIN SMALL LETTER A (U+0061) and COMBINING TILDE (U+0303).  "ã̈" is definitely more that one codepoint.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the maximum **Unicode** character (UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 are *encodings* of Unicode to bytes) is U+10FFFF, which fits comfortably in a 4-byte `wchar_t`.

As for the 2 bytes `wchar_t`, Unicode addressed this problem in UTF-16 by adding in dummy "surrogate" characters in the range U+D800 to U+DFFF.

Quoting an example from the [UTF-16 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16):

> To encode U+10437 () to UTF-16:
>   Subtract 0x10000 from the code point, leaving 0x0437.
>   For the high surrogate, shift right by 10 (divide by 0x400), then add 0xD800, resulting in 0x0001 + 0xD800 = 0xD801.
>   For the low surrogate, take the low 10 bits (remainder of dividing by 0x400), then add 0xDC00, resulting in 0x0037 + 0xDC00 = 0xDC37.

For completeness' sake, here is this character encoded in different encodings:

- UTF-8:    0xF0 0x90 0x90 0xB7
- UTF-16:   0xD801 0xDC37
- UTF-32:   0x00010437